# Block 'Explore' feature on Google Docs for users under Google Family Link

Tags: parental-control, google-family-link, google-docs

I tried to put my boy under my supervision on Google Family Link. I put a limited number of apps on his phone, only what he needs without a browser at all. One of the apps it has is Google Docs. Google Docs on smartphones has an option called 'Explore', where you can search the Internet, and it simply links you to Google and acts as a real browser.

To try: open a sample document > enter edit mode (when the cursor is flashing) > click on the drawing of the three dots > Explore

The whole idea was to block the browser so that it would be impossible to surf the Internet, but Google forgot a small hole in their security.

I haven't even found a way to contact Google themselves, but I think that even if I contact them, no one will really care about me.

Does anyone have an idea how to block it?

Comment: Where exactly do you see the explore option in Google Docs? Also, what device are you doing this on?

Comment: Open a sample document > enter edit mode (when the cursor is flashing) > click on the drawing of the three dots > Explore. I am using OnePluse 5t & huawei p smart 2019

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my Pixel 6, and it works, I guess you should have a proxy set up on the browser. You should also be able to see what he is searching and looking at through your Family Link app, so you will still be able to see what sites he goes to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to block it completely. I am not interested in following the child

Comment: Well, I don't think you will be able to get rid of that. As far as I know, there is no way to not allow that Explorer window that comes up. The one thing I can think of (if they need the app) is you can proxy the browser, or use a proxy that has already been set up.